# php-mysqli - In sql query if search for ID, how to get also 5 row above and 5 rows below this result

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

In sql query,  if search for ID, how to get also 5 rows above the value, and 5 rows below this value?

Example: Say you are searching for ID 7 with query

```
"SELECT * FROM `ID` WHERE `ID` = 7"
```

How can I get  IDs 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 and 8,9,10,11,12?

So using a search input form what ever number is entered it then knows to look up and display 5 above and 5 below the value entered.

I hope that makes sence

Comment: `WHERE ID BETWEEN (7-5) AND (7+5)`  Though keep in mind that you're assuming you have an unbroken succession of IDs.

Comment: thank you David for your response, I have also kept that in mind in regards to the succession of IDs. thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`between`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator to select from a range of values. 
In your case, if you want "5 on either side" of 7, then you can have the starting value be 7-5, and have the ending value be 7+5.

```
SELECT * FROM `ID` WHERE `ID` BETWEEN (7-5) and (7+5)
```

Comment: Won't work if IDs are not a consecutive numeric sequence.

Comment: @lubosdz You're correct, but based on the OP's expected output (they list 2 through 12 if the input is 7), they are consecutive numbers. Also, "above" and "below" values usually indicates a numerical or alphabetical sequence. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, fullname, etc FROM (
    SELECT ID, fullname, etc FROM ID WHERE ID < 7 ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 5
    UNION
    SELECT ID, fullname, etc FROM ID WHERE ID > 7 ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 5
) AS t;
```

Declare all fields that you want extract in all SELECT...

Comment: Hi all thanks for your help.
Robbie Toyota - your query was exactly what I required
SELECT * FROM `ID` WHERE `ID` BETWEEN (7-5) and (7+5)

Comment: Yeah!you are welcome. With that selection you extrac by "ids", non by number of results. If lack any ID, the query return less results.